# What is the difference between 'belong in' and 'belong to'?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

What is the difference between, "The book was very boring and it belonged in a dustbin" and "The uniform looks like it belonged to a museum collection".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Belong to* is generally possessive:

> This book belongs to me = This is my book.

*Belong in* (or *on* or_under_, etc) indicates that something should be in (or on, or under) a certain position:

> This book belongs in a dustbin = This book should be in a dustbin.

In case of the museum collection, actually both are possible, but they have a different meaning:

> The uniform looks like it belonged to a museum collection.

It looks like there is a museum that has this uniform in its collection. The uniform looks like it was removed from that collection.

> The uniform looks like it belonged in a museum collection.

This uniform may not literally be taken from a museum, but it *should* be in a museum.

Another example to show the difference:

> That car looks like it belongs to John's collection.

The car may have been stolen from John.

> That car looks like it belongs in John's collection.

I think John should buy that car. It fits with the rest of his collection.

Comment: Small typo: `may bot`, otherwise very good answer :)

Comment: Just reading the sentence, would it read clearer if instead of both it said not?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It makes no sense with _both_. If hasty editing were a punishable offence I would certainly get to serve hard time. :)

Comment: Haha we all do it time to time :P.